# Powershell runquery in clients machine ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, shell, powershell, client-server, client-side

I want to get the program names installed from Windows Store(client side). Heres my code. First of all is it possible? Secondly if yes why my code is not working?

```
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();

         // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            shell.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module Appx");
            shell.Commands.AddScript("Get-AppxPackage ");
            Command c = new Command("Out-String");
            c.Parameters.Add("width", 150);
            shell.Commands.AddCommand(c);
          //  var results = shell.Invoke();
            Collection<PSObject> results = shell.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
```

No results returned (Only one and it is empty . )